# Is this is because of Javascript beign single threaded?

Tags: javascript

I came across a snippet like this

```
(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i)
   })
  }
}())
```

I expected it to log 1,2.... instead it logged 3. Not sure if this is because js beign single threaded,& looking the queue only after finishing the loop.

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/t1eokqa1/4/)

Comment: Yes, it is. Are you asking about how to avoid this, or were you simply looking for confirmation of the observed behaviour?

Comment: Your timeout function executes after your loop is finished. At that time your `i` is equal to 3 which is y it always log 3.

Comment: Even (especially) if JS was multithreaded - this solution wouldn't guarantee to return `1, 2, 3` in a row.

Answer (score 8):

It is because JavaScript executes in `async` manner. When `console.log(i)` was executing, the `for loop` completed its iteration and as JavaScript does not have block level scope the value of `i` in `console.log(i)` became `3` for all the iterations.

A workaround for this is using IIFE and passing `i` into the scope:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i)
    });

  })(i);
}
```

[Read More about IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Answer (score 0):

This is because The call to setTimeout() function will initialize the timer.so once the timer is set up the rest of the statements after the call will get executed. Once the current execution stack is completed the calls to the timer will take place.

You can get a clear idea from [this video from a JSConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) about how it happens